# What format is needed for AbsoluteMove in Onvif PTZ. C#

Tags: c#, wsdl, ip-camera, onvif

I am trying to move an onvif camera to a specific pan and tilt position using the AbsoluteMove command. I am not having any problems with ContinuousMove, works as expected. I understand that the position is between -1 and 1. If someone has an example that would be great.

```
Test.ptzClient.ContinuousMove(
     Test.currentProfile,//profile token
     new PTZSpeed() //Velocity
            {
             PanTilt = new Vector2D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.y, panSpeed),
                    y = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.y, tiltSpeed)          
                    },
             Zoom = new Vector1D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.y, zoomSpeed)
                    }
            },
     null);//TimeOut -optional
```

This ^^ works perfectly

```
Test.ptzClient.AbsoluteMove(
     Test.currentProfile,//ProfileToken
     new PTZVector() //Position
            {
             PanTilt = new Vector2D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.y, Test.pan),
                    y = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.y, Test.tilt)
                   },
             Zoom = new Vector1D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.y, Test.zoom)
                   }

             },
     new PTZSpeed() //Speed
            {
             PanTilt = new Vector2D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzPanSpeedLimits.y, Test.pan),
                    y = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzTiltSpeedLimits.y, Test.tilt)
                    },
             Zoom = new Vector1D()
                   {
                    x = Mathf.Lerp(Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.x, Test.ptzZoomSpeedLimits.y, Test.zoom)
                    }
             });
```

this returns: ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

I've tried using null so that it would just use the default ptzspeed, no effects.

Any Ideas?